# Proving a certain continuously differentiable function is one-to-one and onto

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. Suppose $\exists c > 0$ such that $f'(x) > c$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show $f$ is onto and one-to-one.

---

Clearly, $f$ is one-to-one because it's strictly increasing. But how can I show it's onto?

I've tried for a while but can't get it.

I think it will use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: HInt. Can you compare the function to $g(x) = cx+ f(0)$? (Yes, the intermediate value theorem will help.)

Comment: What do you mean compare the function to that? I know that $f(x) \geq f(0) + cx$ since it's strictly increasing. How can I use the Intermediate Value Theorem from here?

Comment: What you know tells you that the values of $f$ grow without bound. Since at some point $f(x) > f(0) + 1000$, the intermediate value theorem tells you $f$ assumes every value between $f(0)$ and $f(0) + 1000$. Nothing special about $1000$. Then figure out how to deal with negative $x$.

Answer (score 3):

By intermediate value theorem, $f$ is surjective if $\displaystyle\sup_{r\in\mathbb R}f(r)=\infty$ and $\displaystyle\inf_{r\in\mathbb R}f(r)=-\infty$.

We prove this by contradiction. Suppose $f(r)<\alpha,\,\forall r\in\mathbb R$ for some $\alpha>0$. Then by mean value theorem, there exists some $0<a<\frac{2\alpha}c$ such that $f(\frac{2\alpha}c)-f(0)=f'(a)\times\frac{2\alpha}c>2\alpha$. But this is impossible since $|f(\frac{2\alpha}c)-f(0)|<\alpha+\alpha=2\alpha$.

The proof that $\displaystyle\inf_{r\in\mathbb R}f(r)=-\infty$ is similar.

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By continuity, $f$ maps intervals to intervals, and from the condition we get for $a\le b$
$$f(b)-f(a)\ge c(b-a)$$
Then consider any number $s>f(0)$.
Then with $x=\frac{s-f(0)}c$, we have $f(x)-f(0)\ge cx=s-f(0)$, thus $s\in [f(0), f(x)]$, so it has a preimage in $[0, x] $.
The case for $s<f(0)$ can be similarly done.

Comment: How does this show the function is onto?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: In the first line, should it be $a < b$? Or is what you wrote, $a \leq b$, correct?

Comment: It doesn't matter, as we get $0\ge0$ when $a=b$.

Comment: When $y < f(0)$, we can set $x = (f(0)-s)/c$?

Comment: Yes, I think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mean value theorem. For any $b>a$ we have for some $d\in(a,b)$
$$f(b)=(b-a)f'(d)+f(a).$$
Take $a=0$, then by the fact that $f'(x)>c>0$ we can see that $f(b)$ increases at least linearly with $b$, so any number greater than $f(0)$ can be attained by $f$. Similar reasoning can be used to show any value smaller than $f(0)$ can be attained by by $f$.